# Custom akka persistence (Play!) JSON (de)serializer

Tags: json, scala, serialization, persistence, akka

I have my relevant actors' messages (de)serializable to/from Play! JSON. I'd like to use JSON (de)serializers for akka persistance system (if possbile).

In [akka persistance](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala/persistence.html#custom-serialization) documentation there is possibility to use our own serializers. Further more [here](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala/serialization.html#serialization-scala) are the instructions how to write custom serializers. Since [akka.serialization.Serializer](http://doc.akka.io/api/akka/2.0/akka/serialization/Serializer.html) is expecting `toBinary` and `fromBinary` is there any way to use Play JSON serializers with akka persistence?

Thank you!

Best!

Comment: What is JSON after all? Can you serialize it to a `String`? Can you serialize `String` into a `Array[Byte]`?

Comment: Did you find an easy way to do it by any chance ?

Answer (score 0):

Where do you like to serialize data to?
I'm looking for a mongodb based akka persistence store with serialized objects using the json formats on my own. Maybe the following driver might be interesting for you as well:
https://github.com/scullxbones/akka-persistence-mongo/issues/16

Answer (score 0):

Integrating play json into akka-persistence is complicated since play json uses instances of `Format` that are gathered via implicits. Akka provides just `java.lang.Object` for  serialization and a `java.lang.Class[_]` for deserialization which makes resolving the correct implicit `Format` impossible.

What you could do is write a custom `akka.serialization.Serializer` that has a `Map` from `Class[A]` to `Format[A]`. This map can be used to find the correct format for a `java.lang.Object` / `java.lang.Class[_]`:

```
class JsonSerializer(serializers: Map[Class[_], Format[_]]) extends Serializer {
  val charset: Charset = StandardCharsets.UTF_8
  val identifier: Int = "play-json-serializer".##
  val includeManifest: Boolean = true

  def serializer[A](c: Class[_]): GenericFormat[A] = serializers.get(c) match {
    case Some(format) => format.asInstanceOf[GenericFormat[A]]
    case None => throw new RuntimeException("No Format available for " + c.getName)
  }

  def toBinary(o: AnyRef): Array[Byte] = jsonSerialize(o).getBytes(charset)
  def fromBinary(bytes: Array[Byte], manifest: Option[Class[_]]): AnyRef = jsonDeserialize(bytes, manifest.get)

  def jsonSerialize[A](a: A): String = {
    implicit val format: GenericFormat[A] = serializer[A](a.getClass)
    Json.stringify(Json.toJson(a))
  }

  def jsonDeserialize[A](bytes: Array[Byte], manifest: Class[_]): A = {
    implicit val format: GenericFormat[A] = serializer[A](manifest)
    Json.fromJson[A](Json.parse(new String(bytes, charset))).get
  }
}
```

You can now inherit this class and pass play formats for all types that your akka-serializer should be able to (de)serialize to the constructor. This serializer must be configured in the akka configuration [as described in the documentation](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/persistence.html#custom-serialization):

```
class MyJsonSerializer extends JsonSerializer(Map(
  Serializer[Foo], Serializer[...], ...
))

// Just a utility class for the pretty syntax above
object Serializer {
  def apply[A](implicit format: Format[A], ctag: ClassTag[A]): (Class[A], Format[A]) =
    (ctag.runtimeClass.asInstanceOf[Class[A]], format)
}
```